# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with a non-ASCII string in Windows?

Tags: java, encoding, runtime.exec

Trying the following method to open an Arabic URL:

```
  String cmd = "cmd.exe /C start \"Open file\" \"http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/موسوعة\"";
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
```

Unfortunately, the URL being opened is `http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/??????`

Any thoughts on why this is or how I could prevent this?

---

Before you ask why I don't use java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(), it's because of this Sun bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6457572

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this particular example to work - i.e. open an URL with UTF-8 in it, try this:

```
String params = URLEncoder.encode("موسوعة", "utf-8");
String cmd = "cmd.exe /C start \"Open file\" \"http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + params + "\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```